# Evolution Mail and Calendar Authentication Error

Tags: 14.04, evolution, gmail

I am having a problem in adding my gmail id in Evolution Mail and Calendar. There is always this authentication error message.
What are the possible reasons for this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try enabling access to your Google account for so-called 'less secure apps' on https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Then, can you share how you have set up your Gmail account? Did you use the general Online Accounts section on the Ubuntu settings screen or did you configure your Gmail account in Evolution manually without it being mentioned in the Online Accounts list?

In some forum threads about similar issues it is reported that setting up a Google account in Evolution works while going via the Online Accounts setup does not...